# Find the solutions of the equation $z^2+2z+1-i=0$ in the form$ z=p+iq$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I had tried this so far :
let $z = x + iy$
Hence, $$(x + iy)^2 + 2 (x + iy) + 1 - i = 0$$
$$x^2 + 2xyi + - y^2 + 2x + 2iy + 1 - i = 0$$
$$x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 1 + 2xyi + 2iy - i = 0$$

Comment: I think this will be easier if we treat $z$ in its entirety as a complex variable. For example, the given equation is the same as $(z+1)^2 = i$ ... what are the square roots of $i$ in the complex numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Gotta get used to the fact that complex numbers are actually numbers in their own right.

$z^2 +2z + 1-i=0$ will have solutions by the quadratic formula of

$z = \frac {-2 \pm \sqrt {4 - 4(1-i)}}2$

So factoring out the common factor $2$ we get $z = -1\pm i^{\frac 12}=$

$-1 \pm (\frac 1{\sqrt 2} + \frac 1{\sqrt 2}i) =$

$(-1\pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2}) + i(\pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2})$.

....

Although you could continue.

You must solve $x^2 - y^2 + 2x + 1=0$ and $2xy + 2y-1 = 0$.

So $y = x^2 +2x + 1$ so $y = (x+1)^2$ and $y = \pm(x+1)$.

But we also have $2xy + 2y - 1 = 0$ so $y(2x+2) = 1$ and $y = \frac 1{2(x+1)}$.

So we must solve $\pm (x+1) = \frac 1{2(x+1)}$ or

$\pm (x+1)^2 = \frac 12$ so $(x+1)^2 = \frac 12$ (and $y > 0$) and $x+1 =\pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ and ... the rest falls out.

$x = -1 \pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ and $y = \pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

(I actually wasn't expecting it to fall out so neatly.)

Answer (score 1):

It's way easier to keep the complex variable whole

$$z^2+2z+1=(z+1)^2=i 
\implies z = -1\pm\sqrt{i} = -1\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: You shouldn't use the notation $\sqrt i$.   It is not defined as a function on $\mathbf C$.

Comment: @Bernard what in the world are you talking about? All principal roots by default use the principal branch of log. This is well defined, perhaps what you mean is that it is not analytic on all of  $\Bbb{C}$. If I could downvote a comment for being unhelpful I would.

Comment: @Bernard you mean $\sqrt i$ is wrong notation. Do I understand right?

Comment: @lonestudent: yes. I prefer to speak of the square roots of $i$ explicitly, it's less dangerous for beginners.

Comment: @Bernard it's because of attitudes like that students are afraid of ambiguities of complex powers in the first place. The notation here is not incorrect or unrigorous. I am of the camp to use notations such as $\sqrt{}$ or rational powers interchangeably because they don't mean anything different by themselves and anyone who believes they do is naive. Distinctions may be made by different authors for the purposes of illustrating different conventions, but I have seen authors call both the $\sqrt{}$ and power notation the principal and multiimage function because there is no consistency.

Comment: @Bernard It is possible to see this notation in YouTube math channels, Google images and web searches.  But I never knew it was wrong.. Thanks.

Comment: @lonestudent the take away is not that the notation is wrong, that is an incorrect conclusion. The point that Bernard was (hopefully) trying to make is that there is a principal and multibranched version of complex roots and we should know when we are using which. But it is a common misconception that this phenomenon is unique to complex numbers. We write $\sqrt{x}$ to mean the positive root only in the real case, and this is not any different from what we do in the complex case. However Bernard's initial comment about $\sqrt{z}$ not being a defined function on $\Bbb{C}$ is mostly wrong

Comment: @NinadMunshi Using radicals for the principal value is not wrong per se as long as the definition has been made clear. But it is not universal, and can be confusing especially for those unaccustomed to that convention. Just look at how many questions have been posted (usually about math softwares) $\text{"}\,$why is $\sqrt[3]{-1}$" not $-1\,?\,\text{"}$.

Comment: @dxiv if we use $\sqrt{x}$ to take the positive branch in the real case, then we can take $\sqrt{z}$ to mean the principal branch, always. Case closed. Convince me that these situations are different and I'll agree that ambiguity is warranted.

Comment: @Bernard  (sorry for English grammar) There is a sentence like this in my school book." To write $i=\sqrt {-1}$ is wrong. Because, $\sqrt {•}$ must use for only positive reals. So, we can write only $i^2=-1$". I want to post this question in MSE as a question for a long time, but I didn't do it because it might be not a good question. Would you like to say something? Thank you..

Comment: Personally, I write in plain language: ‘$i$ is a square root of $-1$’ (the other being $-i$). If one uses the notation $\sqrt z$, you're not sure that $\sqrt{zz'}=\sqrt z\,\sqrt{z'}$ in all cases.

Comment: @NinadMunshi "*then we* ***can*** *take √z to mean the principal*". Right, but with emphasis on "*can*". It is not universal, and it helps for that convention to be spelled out when used. Ask random people what $\Re(\sqrt{4}+i\sqrt[3]{-8})$ is without providing additional context, and you'll probably receive different answers.

Comment: @lonestudent The radical symbol isn't useful in the complex world because there is no universally-good way to define principal root in the complex world, i.e., it is potentially ambiguous unless prefaced.
$$$$
E.g., does $\sqrt[3]{-1}$ equal $e^{i\frac\pi3}$ (choose the root with the smallest nonnegative argument) or $-1$ (choose the positive root if it exists; else the negative root; else the root with the smallest positive argument)?....

Comment: @dxiv ....A kookier example: $1$ has infinitely many positive $i^\text{th}$ roots: $e^{2k\pi}=\{\ldots,e^{-4\pi}, e^{-2\pi}, 1, e^{2\pi}, \dots\};$ here, both the above criteria fail to settle on a "principal root". $$$$ So, I studiously treat the radical symbol as having a nonnegative domain, and,  **in the complex world**, treat expressions like $1^\frac12$ and $i^\frac12$ as multi-valued (but this convention also isn't universal: many feel that, even in the complex world, $1^\frac12=1\neq\{-1,1\}$).

Answer (score 0):

Along the line of what you were trying, it may be a bit easier (for *this* problem) to bring the "numerical" terms to one side of the equation, producing
$$ z^2 \ + \ 2z \ \ = \ \ (p^2 + 2p - q^2) \ + \ (2pq + 2q)·i \ \ =  \ \ -1 \ + \ i \ \ . $$
We can then set up the correspondence equations
$$ p^2  +  2p  - q^2 \ \ = \ \ -1 \ \ \ , \ \ \ 2·q·(p + 1) \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ . $$
From the first of these, we obtain $ \ p^2  +  2p  + 1 \  =  \ ( p + 1 )^2 \
= \ q^2 \ \ . $  Squaring the second equation yields $ \ 4·q^2·(p + 1)^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ . $  Consequently, $$ \ 4·q^2·q^2 \ = \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ \ q \ = \ \left(\frac14 \right)^{1/4} \ = \ \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ = \ \pm ( p + 1 ) \ \ . $$
It is evident, since the polynomial is quadratic, that two of the four possible combinations must be "spurious."  Our second correspondence equation requires that $ \ (p + 1) \ $ and $ \ q \ $ must have the same sign, so the two zeroes of the polynomial are $ \ z \ = \ \left(-1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \right) \ \pm \ \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \right)·i \ \ . $